# How to replace values in xml from sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an xml in my SQL Server table like this:

```
<Category>
    <Attributes>
        <Attribute>
            <Name>GeneratorOnBoard1</Name>
            <Value>Yes</Value>
        </Attribute>
        <Attribute>
            <Name>GeneratorOnBoard2</Name>
            <Value>Yes</Value>
        </Attribute>
    </Attributes>
</Category>
```

I want to replace the value of GeneratorOnBoard1 from 'yes' to 'yes please'
but should not change the value of GeneratorOnBoard2.

If I use this:

```
declare @xml xml=''

select cast (replace (cast(@xml as nvarchar(max)), 'yes','yes please') as xml)
```

it might replace all the yes values.

What should I do?

Comment: Which database is this?

Comment: mssql..........................

Comment: Refer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12545964/updating-xml-attributes-with-new-values-in-a-sql-server-2008-table hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Bit easy and alternative way is to use `STUFF` with `PATINDEX` as below

```
SELECT 
    STUFF(CAST(@xml AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), 
           PATINDEX('%Yes%', CAST(@xml AS NVARCHAR(MAX))), 3, 'Yes Please');
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at using [replace value of (XML DML)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/replace-value-of-xml-dml?view=sql-server-2017).

```
declare @xml xml = '<Category>
    <Attributes>
        <Attribute>
            <Name>GeneratorOnBoard1</Name>
            <Value>Yes</Value>
        </Attribute>
        <Attribute>
            <Name>GeneratorOnBoard2</Name>
            <Value>Yes</Value>
        </Attribute>
    </Attributes>
</Category>';

set @xml.modify('replace value of (/Category
                                    /Attributes
                                     /Attribute[(Name/text())[1] = "GeneratorOnBoard1" and
                                                (Value/text())[1] = "Yes"]
                                      /Value/text())[1] 
                 with "yes please"');
```

Comment: it will replace all the values of generatoronboard valuse ryt? i dont want to replace if value is no, only for yes i need to change

Comment: @hilda_sonica_vish No it will not. It will only replace the the first value it finds. If you want to replace multiple values you have to do that in a loop. I added the condition that the Value has to be "Yes" to my answer.